# Configuring DNS on my web-server (BIND9)

Tags: ubuntu, dns, webserver

I'm about to set up a web-server in my home, I have acquired a fixed IP, the hardware and a domain name. I have chosen a server solution consisting of Ubuntu Server 10.01 with BIND9 (DNS), Apache2, PHP, MySQL and some mailserver solution.
Hence, the DNS server must point towards itself for nameserver (eg. ns1.example.com), mailserver (eg. mail.example.com) and the site itself (eg. example.com).
Can this be done or do i have to psychically set up 2/3 servers? And how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one IP address for your LAMP configuration, but usually registrars requires 2 nameservers, in that case you'll have to configure secondary IP address on your server.

If you don't need to have your own nameservers, I would recommend using one of the free/commercial DNS services.